How to write the SQL statement to get latest result under given condition
Given the following data:



id
contract no.
estate
type
build date
remarks




1
00001
1a
B
20241101
ewr


2
00001
LR
C
20240101
adfd


3
00001
1b
X
20231005
wer


4
00001
1c
C2
20231005



5
00002
2a
B
20241005



6
00002
2b
C
20240205



7
00003
3a
A1
20240602



8
00003
3b
X
20240602



9
00004
4a
D
20240502



10
00004
4b
X
20230101




how to use SQL (for SQL Server) to get each contract no., if it has estate = 'LR', then get the record with latest build date before 'LR', and if have two record with same date, then choose type = 'X' first.
If for given contract no., no estate = 'LR', then choose the record with latest build date, if have same build date, choose type = 'X' first.
This would be the expected output for the above sample data:



id
contract no.
estate
type
build date
remarks




3
00001
1b
X
20231005
wer


5
00002
2a
B
20241005



8
00003
3b
X
20240801



9
00004
4a
D
20240502





Please ask a clear and concrete question rather than simply ask "how to...". This site is no SQL tutorial, so you should at least provide your closest attempt and explain what exactly doesn't work as expected.

I created a fiddle to help us colaborate on a solution. This is close https://dbfiddle.uk/f6lEBa3A

This might do it https://dbfiddle.uk/e6AWlH2E

The linked "duplicate" answer only address a part of the requirements. This db<>fiddle shows a combination of contract LR date lookup, source data filtering, and "Get top 1 row of each group" logic to get the desired results. It uses a CTE and a window function to first look up the LR build date for each contract. It uses a second CTE to filter the source data by that LR build data (when present) and to number the rows based on the defined preference order (latest build date and Type = 'X' as a tiebreaker). The final select picks the top row for each contract.

@Bart McEndree Great! this really solve the problem, if you post it as answer, I will mark it as accepted answer, thanks. I think a long time and cannot solve it by myself.
